# TextView background is stretching

Tags: android, textview

I want to set background to a `TextView` and I want the size of the `TextView` to be in size of the background and the text.

here's my code:

```
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/attackeNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:paddingRight="35dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="thej hhekj hejk hjkesd ks dkl jsalkj dkl"
        android:background="@drawable/attackee_name_background"/>
```

the outcome is, that the text fits inside the 'padding box' just fine, but the background is stretched.

do I have to assign a fixed `layout_width` to the `TextView` ?

Comment: just assign to background the property fit center ;)

Comment: You can use bacground image as [9 patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

Comment: how to I assign property to the background?

Comment: @Lalit Poptani: 9-patch are used for stretching the background, no?

Comment: Yes, can create a background image with 9 patch and that will be managed without getting streched.

Comment: I'm trying to make a 9-patch, with the draw-9-patch tool, but it shows that the whole image is bad patches

Comment: thats because you might be creating it in a wrong way. :)

Comment: well, on the eclipse graphical layout it look ok, but in the device its not. I try to make a different background and see what happens

Comment: @Lalit Poptani: same thing. on the graphical layout it looks ok but on the device I can see the black pixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that the background fits exactly your `TextView` size without stretching and that text fits inside, you have to use a `9-patch` image or you have to set a fixed size equals to image dimensions. There are no other solutions.

Consider also that `padding` reduces the text box area only (the background is not shrinked) while `margin`s leave space outside the `TextView` box.

So if the background image is `(image_width, image_height)` and you want to leave a padding inside the `TextView` without streching the background and without using a `9-patch` image, you have to set a fixed size to `TextView` equals to `(image_width+paddingLeft+paddingRight, image_height+paddingTop+paddingBottom)`.

Comment: +1 For mentioning that margin will adjust the size of the background while padding won't.

Comment: I am using *.9.png image in drawable folder. but does not crunching 9-patch image making build time. Please suggest... how to use 9-patch imge in android project ?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT

here is a hacky way of doing what you want...

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/something" />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` doesn't work. if I make a 9-patch, do I need to set a content area for it, right?

Comment: ya so fill is right and bottom and then scale is top and left.

Comment: I dont want it to scale, thats what i'm trying to prevent. it doesn't work at all

Comment: i wrote something that will work but is probably not the best solution. Im sure there are more clever ways to solve your problem.

Comment: if by 'whatever' you mean a fix size, I can give the size to the textview itself and thats it.

Comment: ya the textview size is the same size as the framelayout since it matches it so from your example I would put wrap_content

Comment: hmm i tested it and seemed to work for me. Sorry I cant be more helpful. To be honest I always hated the way Android handles views. I jsut tested again and i am now 100% sure this works unless I am unsure of what you are asking. Remember layouts can be nested. Like you can put this inside a relative layout somewhere etc although the more nesting the slower the xml inflator is meaning the longer it will take to load the screen. also the drawable does not ahve to be a nine patch and because you are using an imageview here android:scaleType="fitCenter" should work

Comment: well, the background doesn't stretched, but the now the text is outside the background. I think I stick with setting a fixed size